# How to store and use a large set of X and Y coordinates In visual basic

Tags: vb.net, image, coordinates, maze

I have analysed an image and it has collected all of the XY coordinates of pixels that are black. It is 6628 lines long. In the format of:
Example:

20, 552

26, 552

32, 552

I am making a maze game and all of these coordinates values is the perimeter of the black walls. How can I mass import of these coordinates so I can use them?

Comment: Depending on the layout of the walls, [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) might give a useful reduction in the size of the data to store. Or just store the end-ponts of line segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET has a built in structure for this called "point". If you are collecting points you would make a collection of points.

In the code that analyzes the image you would store them as you go:

EXAMPLE:

```
Dim points As New List(Of Point)
points.Add(New Point(X, Y))
```

COLLECTIONS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/collections

POINT:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point.-ctor

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is read the file and parse the text into points.

To read the file line-by-line you can use the [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

When you have a line, you can [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) it on the delimiter character and if the correct number of items were found then [try parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) the individual parts as integers. If that worked, you can add the data to a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)(Of Point):

```
Function GetData(filename As String) As List(Of Point)
    Dim pts As New List(Of Point)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    For Each a In File.ReadLines(filename)
        Dim parts = a.Split({","c}).Select(Function(p) p.Trim()).ToList()
        If parts.Count = 2 Then
            If Integer.TryParse(parts(0), x) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(parts(1), y) Then
                pts.Add(New Point(x, y))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return pts

End Function
```